# How to turn a function into an async validator for a formcontrol in Angular8?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form control of type date that allows the user to pick a date.
I want to create an async validator that checks if the the date submitted already exists x amount of times in my database.
If so, provide an error along the lines of:

```
order.get('DateOfDelivery').errors?.exists
```

I've created this function inside my class shop component (and it works against my db. it comes back with the appropriate amount of orders on queried date):

```
  checkDeliveriesDate(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    let date = { date: event.target.value };
    this.SS.getOrdersPerDate(date).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        /*
        if (res.length>3){
          formcontrol for e should turn invalid 
        }
        else{
          valid
        }
        */
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }
```

here's the form control. I know that the async validator needs to be the third argument-

```
DateOfDelivery: new FormControl('', Validators.required),/*AsyncValidatorHere*/),
```

Here's the HTML-

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="DateOfDelivery" (change)='checkDeliveriesDate($event)'>
```

I appreciate the help.
Thank you in advance

Edit:

```
checkDeliveriesDateValidator(ctrl: AbstractControl) {

  if (!ctrl || String(ctrl.value).length === 0) {
    console.log("!c|| String (c.value).length ===0")
    return null;

  }

  return (ctrl && ctrl.value) ? this.SS.getOrdersPerDate({ date: ctrl.value }).pipe(
    map(res => {
      let deliveriesDate:any=res;
      console.log(deliveriesDate);
      if (deliveriesDate.length>3){ 
        return {exists: true};
      }
      else{
        return null;
      }
    })
  ) : null;
}
```

The async validator is producing this error-

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'SS' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

you return the observable and use the map operator to transform the response into the validator return type, and also make it expect an abstract control as argument, like so:

```
 checkDeliveriesDateValidator(ctrl: AbstractControl) {
    // add in basic null checks
    return (ctrl && ctrl.value) ? this.SS.getOrdersPerDate({ date: ctrl.value }).pipe(
      map(res => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.length>3){
          //formcontrol for e should turn invalid 
          return {exists: true};
        }
        else{
          return null;
        }
      })
    ) : null;
  }
```

then use like:

```
DateOfDelivery: new FormControl('', Validators.required, checkDeliveriesDateValidator)
```

Comment: Hi there, I did what you suggested (I think- edited the original post) but I am getting a console error since this.SS (this is undefined so ss (shop service) can't execute the method getOrdersPerDate